# VBA Assign a RecordSet Field to a ComboBox

Tags: vba, ms-access, combobox

I have the following code:

```
sSQL = "SELECT CODER FROM " & dbfname & " IN " & dir & " WHERE TRIM(CODEK) = TRIM(kCode)"
Combo29.RowSource = sSQL
Combo29.Requery
```

, where "CODER" is a field in the dbf file. "CODEK" is also a field in that dbf file, which im comparing with the string kCode.

When I run the code and when I click on the combobox, it asks me to enter arguments instead of showing the selected arguments. The RowSource type is set to Table/Query.

Is the assigning statement incorrect and how can I modify it to show me list of results from the SQL statement?

Comment: try `" WHERE TRIM(CODEK) = 'kCode'"`

Comment: I will run some checks and try again. The ENter value msg disappeared, but there are no values in the combobx for now.

Comment: I'm not sure what your `" IN " & dir` part suppose to do?

Comment: dir is just a String containing the path to the dbf file.

Comment: You have a variable named "dir".  But VBA includes a function named `Dir`.  Include `Debug.Print sSQL` in your code so you can examine that `SELECT` statement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your problem correctly `kCode` is a string in VBA so you'll have to set up your SQL string the following way

```
sSQL = "SELECT CODER FROM " & dbfname & " IN " & dir & " WHERE TRIM(CODEK) = TRIM('" & kCode & "')"`
```